# Bootstrap - Change width of a <div> without changing height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Excuse me, I'm not so fond of Bootstrap, but I'm trying to change **ONLY the width** of my container named div class="row border border-secondary mx-auto", **without resizing the height of div element and the height of content** image when I include property w-50 into my class. Pic related what happens, I only want to trim of the edges on the side and basically wrap my image into that div, which will have a fixed width and height.

I played around a bit and searched around, but still don't know what else to do, other than change it to px, but then it doesn't resize proportionally when minimizing page.

```
    <div class="row border border-secondary mx-auto">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3">
                <a href="/profile/{{ $post->user->id }}">
                    <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100">
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeYU8.png

Comment: Hi, if you can provide your CSS code that would help. If your `div` has fixed height and width, then try making the image dimensions with 100% height and width to fit the container.

My guess is, as per the code you provided, when you added `w-100` class for the image, it also sets the `height` to automatically adjust based on the image's width. So you can try to restrict the image height as well.

Comment: It's basically just Bootstrap CDN I think - 

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

Comment: I was talking about the image inside the div. It has only width class as per your code, specify a height for it and let us know if it worked.

Comment: I found answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution - basically removed the col-6 offset-3 class and added some styling to image that you'd usually use to fit an image into div.

```
<div class="row border border-secondary mx-auto w-50">
            <div>
                <a href="/profile/{{ $post->user->id }}">
                    <img style="
                       max-width: 100%; 
                       max-height: 100%; 
                       display: block; 
                       height: 600px;"

                    src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}">
                </a>
            </div>
</div>
```